# How can I find EdgeWeights strongly connected components using Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, programming

Given the following `Code`:

```
Clear[edgeW, gr, m, mm, sa, wG, ledgeW, paths, pathMult, sccL, grSCCl];
edgeW = Module[{g = #, 
 e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
   FindPath[##, \[Infinity], All]}, 
Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;
Manipulate[
SeedRandom[1245];
mm = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
gr = RandomGraph[{n, m}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"]; (*full graph*)
sa = SparseArray[AdjacencyMatrix[gr]*mm];
wG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
ledgeW = Length@edgeW[wG, 11, 15];
paths = Table[  edgeW[wG, 11, 15][[p, 1]], {p, 1, ledgeW}  ];
pathMult = {paths, {Table[
Times @@ 
     Table[ edgeW[wG, 11, 15][[p, 2]], {p, 1, ledgeW} ][[i]], {i, 
     1, ledgeW}
    ]} // Transpose} // Transpose // MatrixForm;
sccL = MaximalBy[Length]@ConnectedComponents[wG];
grSCCl = Subgraph[wG, sccL, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
Grid[{{pathMult, gr}, {"", grSCCl}}],
{{m, 25}, 25, 45, 5}
]
```

I generate the following figure, the first row of which includes all the possible pathways from a source `11` to a sink `15`. I calculate multipliers for each pathway given in the matrix form.

I simply want to replicate the calculation of the pathway multipliers using the strongly connected component. I do not want to re-write the same code twice to generate the multipliers. How can I automate the calculations of the multipliers for the full graph and its largest SCC using `Manipulate`?

Furthermore, I like to place multiplier values on the SCC.

[image]

Comment: is `n = 17`? :)

Comment: `n` is the number of vertices. Sorry I forgot to include `n=17` in the `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[edgeW, gr, m, n, mm, sa, wG, paths, pathMult, sccL, grSCCl];
n = 17;

edgeW = Module[{g = #, e = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ FindPath[##, ∞, All]}, 
    Transpose[{e, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ # & /@ e}]] &;

Manipulate[SeedRandom[1245];
  mm = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
  gr = RandomGraph[{n, m}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"]; sa = SparseArray[AdjacencyMatrix[gr]*mm];
  wG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
    DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
  paths = edgeW[wG, 11, 15][[All, 1]];
  pathMult = {paths, {Times @@@ edgeW[wG, 11, 15][[All, 2]]} // 
      Transpose} // Transpose // MatrixForm;
  sccL = MaximalBy[Length]@ConnectedComponents[wG];
  grSCCl = Subgraph[wG, sccL, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{wG, e}, EdgeWeight]}, 
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center, Round[#, .01] &]];
  pathMult2 = First @ Reverse @ SortBy[{Length @* First, First @* Last}] @ pathMult[[1]];
  Grid[{{pathMult, HighlightGraph[gr, Subgraph[wG, sccL]]}, 
     {pathMult2, HighlightGraph[grSCCl, Subgraph[grSCCl, pathMult2]]}}], 
 {{m, 30}, 25, 45, 5}]
```

[image]

**Notes:** (1) You can extract the part you need from `pathMult` since it contains all the information you need. In the example above, I extract the row that corresponds to the longest path with the maximum product of edge weights. (2) I added the options `EdgeWeights` and `EdgeLabels` to `grSCCl`.

Comment: I really appreciate your extended answer to the question.

Comment: In the subgraph on the second row, there are more pathways than the longest pathway given. Which pathways do the red links refer to? Would it be possible to restrict the red links only to the longest pathway given?

Comment: There are two paths with 6 edges in `pathMult`.  `pathMult2` selects the one with the largest product of edgeweights. If you want to show both, you can change the last two lines to `pathMult3 = MaximalBy[Length@*First]@pathMult[[1]];
Grid[{{pathMult, HighlightGraph[gr, Subgraph[wG, sccL]]}, {pathMult3, 
   HighlightGraph[grSCCl, Subgraph[grSCCl, #] & /@ pathMult3]}}` in the first argument of `Manipulate`.

Comment: Now I understand it. This addition is useful, too.